# Is there a way to import a folder of HTML files into the blog?

Tags: import, blog

I have a folder of about 100 HTML files (all marked up consistently) that I want to turn into individual blog posts.

Each one has a paragraph that says "Posted by User on 4/9/2013 5:45:52 PM", but exact dating is not required.

What's the best way?

Comment: what have you tried? here is probably no "best way" as it should be a one time process and no point in optimizing it in any way