# Is there a way to bulk upload HTML files into WordPress as posts or pages?

Tags: uploads

I realize this is a longshot... I have a site running on a proprietary platform ("SiteSell", aka "SBI"). I have over 200 html files from that system on my local computer. Is there some way to bulk upload those into a WordPress site such that each file is one page or post?

When I search for this answer in search engines and here, I don't get an answer... just things like how to bulk import media.

I realize that even if such a tool or technique exists, these pages will start off fairly ugly and will require some effort to clean up, but it seems like it will be a heck of a lot faster/easier than creating each post individually then pasting the html content in.

It appears this question was asked in 2015 but not answered ([Is there a way to import a folder of HTML files into the blog?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177727/is-there-a-way-to-import-a-folder-of-html-files-into-the-blog))

Comment: Same problem. It is *crazy* how hard this is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any tools doing this, but in WordPress a page or post is basically just a row within the [prefix]_posts database table. In your case I would just create a PHP file to contain all the codes you need:

1. Read the HTML file's contents.
2. Process the data to have a title and description.
3. Connect to the database, and upload these to [prefix]_posts.

In a new WordPress installation, within its [prefix]_posts table you could check the "Hello world!" (which is a post) or "Sample Page" (which is a page) post_title containing row, to see what columns you will need to generate.